# Issue with Trello Get Webhooks Api

Tags: webhooks, trello

I am trying to get all the webhooks registered on my boards.

On the Trello developers website, it states the following URL to get the array of webhooks:

```
GET /1/tokens/[token]/webhooks
```

When I try this with my token and app key, I get an empty array (`[]`) back.

In the sandbox, however, it uses a different URL for the same call, and it gives me the response I expected.

```
GET /members/me/tokens?webhooks=true
```

But when I try this in my code, I get "unauthorized member permission requested."

How do I get the list of my webhooks through my code?

Answer (score 1):

Both requests you mentioned will work as long as the user token and application key are supplied in the correct places:

```
GET /1/tokens/[USER_TOKEN]/webhooks?token=[USER_TOKEN]&key=[APPLICATION_KEY]
GET /1/members/me/tokens?webhooks=true&token=[USER_TOKEN]&key=[APPLICATION_KEY]
```

> The `me` keyword in the second request corresponds to the user whose token is supplied in the query parameter. [See the Trello API Reference: GET /1/members/[idMember or username]](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/member#get-1-members-idmember-or-username)